# What would be the reverse of 'Read more' on an expandable/collapsable block of text?

Tags: interface

I'm currently working on a page which features a block of text. This block of text can differ in length, depending on the users search term. On mobile I've decided to truncate the text and include a 'Read more' link. This text sits inside a expandable/collapsable block. When the user clicks on 'Read more' the block will expand to show the full text.

When the block is fully expanded, I want to include a link that will collapse the block back into the original position. I've currently chosen 'Close' as the link text, but I'm concerned it might be slightly ambiguous to users.

I've thought about using Show more/Show less, but as this is a block of text I think Read more is better suited.

Comment: Maybe 'Collapse'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parallel construction: **Read Less**

Collapse and Close are both to close it entirely. Revert would imply an actual data change.

Could also use **Show More**/**Show Less** or just **More**/**Less**. But keep it parallel.

Comment: Agree. Amazon, at least on their [book pages](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00KK6FK40/) for a book's description use **Read more** and **Read less**.

Comment: "Reading is harmful"

Comment: Well, you you already read *more*, you cannot unread it. Therefore Read Less won't help you. What you can undo is your expanding, i.e. *collapse*. Though it was named 'Read More' it is okay to rename it to 'Collapse' as it is what it actually will do. Reading is irrevertable.

Comment: @SergeyKirienko Collapse implies "close the entire thing" unless it is clearly matched to something else. If the original is "Expand" or "Open" then "Collapse" makes sense.

Comment: @manassehkatz I thought "Collapse" would mean "Collapse what you expanded", but probably you are also right.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better solution is "Show more" because it means the next action that will be done. The app won't read the text but will show it to you and you will read it.

Comment: And "show less" accordingly to it.